# What will be the missing number?

Tags: pattern, calculation-puzzle

What number comes next?

11,13,17,19,23,25,?

Comment: Does your sequence stop after the 7th term? Is 11 the first integer in the sequence, or could one also extend it to the left?

Comment: In my opinion, the question isn't too broad. It's just very easy. Only if the intended answer isn't the very straightforward answer Deusovi gave I would say it's too broad. This question has been marked as too broad too soon I think. The asker should have been given the chance to accept Deusovi's answer. The asker obviously is a new member and I think nothing is wrong with very easy questions. This is a typical sequence you see on an IQ test. When you encounter it there you also won't think "Hey this is too broad, I can't answer this", right?

Answer (score 2):

It's 29. The numbers alternate increasing by 2 and 4.